# Как открыть фаил формата jpg_128x96?

Tags: jpeg, photo

На андроиде заметил файлы с таким расширением, фото еще 2009 года. Что это такое? И можно ли как то открыть?

Comment: Уберите _128x96 из расширения - файл скорее всего откроется. Расширение != формат.

Comment: Уже пытался, не работает

Comment: А это точно расширение а не название? И чем открывали? Какое сообщение вылазит при попытке открывать?

Comment: Нет приложения сопоставленного с этим файлом и бла бла бла.  И да, это точно расширение